# Simple PHP form error

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to create a simple PHP email form that I can embed into my website. I have two problems, the syntax appears to be wrong past href=\"\"> and I am not sure why. The rest of the text appears in the browser past that href=\"\"> section. If I use this form, won't it be easier to keep users from seeing my email in this PHP form? Be advised, I am new to PHP

```
<?php 
$action=$_REQUEST['action']; 
if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */ 
    { 
    ?> 
<form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
Your email:<br> 
<input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 
Your message:<br> 
<textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br> 
<input type="submit" value="Send email"/> 
</form> 
<?php 
}  
else                /* send the submitted data */ 
{ 
$email=$_REQUEST['email']; 
$message=$_REQUEST['message']; 
if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message=="")) 
    { 
    echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again."; 
    } 
else{         
    $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email"; 
    $subject="Message sent using your contact form"; 
    mail("me@email.org", $subject, $message, $from); 
    echo "Email sent!"; 
    } 
}   
?>
```

See anything wrong?

Comment: What actually happens when you submit the form? Is an email sent, do you get a white screen/php error message? If the code works as is, this may be better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Try this, `echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=''>the form</a> again.";`

Comment: Where exactly is the name input?????

Comment: Why would you want an empty href ?

Comment: assuming you meant `action` this causes the form to submit to itself... of course, I see issue with cross browser support using this method...

Comment: @thebluedog And what did you see ?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer: Pretty much what has already been pointed out; the empty href, empty action and missing `$name`. Personally, I would use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST'` and the $_POST vars to do the work since it's a post method anyway, but that's not necessarily an issue though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking for `$name` and it doesn't exist. This will get you working but you should check if the `$_REQUEST` exists before you define it. Always write code with error reporting on.

```
<?php 
$action=$_REQUEST['action']; 
if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */ 
    { 
    ?> 
<form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
Your email:<br> 
<input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br> 
Your message:<br> 
<textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br> 
<input type="submit" value="Send email"/> 
</form> 
<?php 
}  
else                /* send the submitted data */ 
{ 
$email=$_REQUEST['email']; 
$message=$_REQUEST['message']; 
if (($email=="")||($message=="")) 
    { 
    echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again."; 
    } 
else{         
    $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email"; 
    $subject="Message sent using your contact form"; 
    mail("me@email.org", $subject, $message, $from); 
    echo "Email sent!"; 
    } 
}   
?>
```

Comment: Nice mod, but I hope he didn't _want_ the name... Never mind the 'other' problem(s).

Comment: Agreed lol. IT looks like it use to be an option then was removed so I assumed it was not needed by looking at the form. He can figure that out tho

Comment: I like your reasoning!